# Image to image regression in tensorflow

Tags: deep-learning, python

I am working on an image to image regression task which requires me to develop a deep learning model that takes in a sequence of 5 images and return another image. The sequence of 5 images and the output images are conceptually and temporally related. In fact, the 5 images in the sequence each correspond to timestep in a simulation and the output, the one I am trying to predict, corresponds eventually to the 6th timestep of that sequence.

For now, I have been training a simple regression-type CNN model which takes in the sequence of 5 images stored in a list and outputs an image corresponding to the next timestep in the simulation.

However, I have been researching a bit now in order to find a better way to carry out this task and I found the idea of ConvLSTMs. However, I have seen these applied to the prediction of feature and the output of a sentence describing that image. What I wanted to know is whether ConvLSTMs can also output images, but more importantly if they can be applied to my case. If not, what other types of deep learning network can be suitable for this task?

Thanks in advance !